# perlbench results in segfault outside the SPEC 2006 harness

Tags: c, perl, debugging, crash, benchmarking

This might be overly specific, but posting here as it might help someone else who's trying to compile/run the SPEC 2006 benchmarks outside the default SPEC benchmark harness. (Our reason of doing this is comparing compiling strategies and code coverage, while the SPEC harness is focused on performance of the resulting code only).

When performing a ref run of perlbench the benchmark crashes with a segmentation fault:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004f6868 in S_regmatch (prog=0x832144)

    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/regexec.c:3024
3024            PL_reg_start_tmp[n] = locinput;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004f6868 in S_regmatch (prog=0x832144)
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/regexec.c:3024
#1  0x00000000004f22cf in S_regtry (prog=0x8320c0, startpos=0x831e70 "o")
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/regexec.c:2196
#2  0x00000000004eba71 in Perl_regexec_flags (prog=0x8320c0, stringarg=0x831e70 "o", strend=0x831e71 "", 
    strbeg=0x831e70 "o", minend=0, sv=0x7e2528, data=0x0, flags=3)
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/regexec.c:1910
#3  0x00000000004b33bb in Perl_pp_match ()
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/pp_hot.c:1340
#4  0x00000000004fcde4 in Perl_runops_standard ()
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/run.c:37
#5  0x000000000046bf57 in S_run_body (oldscope=1)
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/perl.c:2017
#6  0x000000000046b9f6 in perl_run (my_perl=0x7bf010)
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/perl.c:1934
#7  0x000000000047add2 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffe178, env=0x7fffffffe1a0)
    at <path-to-spec>/CPU2006/400.perlbench/src/perlmain.c:98
```

The execution environment is 64-bit Linux and the behaviour is observed with both the latest gcc and clang.

What causes this crash?

Comment: This looks like something different than https://github.com/briandfoy/perlbench, but if it isn't you can create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: It is different indeed. I was not aware of https://github.com/briandfoy/perlbench . The one in this question is a part of the SPEC CPU 2006 benchmark suite and is using (an old version of) the perl interpreter as a benchmark for C compilers and/or hardware;OS;etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The segfault is caused by a garbage value of the variable `n` on the pointed out line. Inspecting the code shows that the value comes from the field `arg1` of an object of type:

```
struct regnode_1 {
    U8  flags;
    U8  type;
    U16 next_off;
    U32 arg1;
};
```

Inspecting the memory location of the object shows that it is not packed, i.e. there is 32bit padding between `next_off` and `arg1`:

```
(gdb) x/16xb scan
0x7f4978:       0xde    0x2d    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7f4980:       0x00    0x11    0x0d    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
(gdb) print/x n
$1 = 0xd1100
```

This is suspicious. There's pointer and type conversion going on in `perlbench`, so perhaps type size assumptions fail somewhere. Compiling with `multilib` yields a working benchmark and examining the memory verifies that there is no padding.

Forcing the structure into a bitfield fixes the crash when performing a 64-bit compile:

```
struct regnode_1 {
    U8  flags : 8;
    U8  type : 8;
    U16 next_off : 16;
    U32 arg1 : 32;
};
```

Comment: In the GNU C dialect of the C language, you could probably also use `__attribute__((packed))` to get the same effect.  Interesting approach to use bitfields to get struct packing without any non-portable syntax.

Comment: We tried using `__attribute__((packed))` first (it is supposed to work on both GCC and clang) but that didn't change the memory layout (possibly we used it wrong). Then we assumed bit fields won't help either so we went through a lot of different approaches before trying this easy one and it worked. But it's definitely duct tape.

Comment: gcc has a warning if you put it before the `struct` keyword, instead of `struct __attribute((packed)) regnode_1`, enabled with `-Wall` at least.  BTW, I'm not seeing any padding with just the normal definition, in the x86-64 SystemV ABI.  Does the Windows ABI struct-layout rules result in padding for this struct?  [Take a look on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/CTmfef), which targets x86-64 Linux by default (System V ABI).  I put in some commented-out `unsigned :1` anonymous padding to show that it does have a different effect on the packed/non-packed structs, but that they're the same without.

Answer (score 2):

This is how our little investigation progressed:

At first we thought it was some padding issue, but as Peter pointed out on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/CTmfef), no such thing occurs. So, the packing or not of the structure did not change anything.

Then, I got suspicious of the (clearly twisted) way that Perl handles pointers. The majority of the casts are violating strict aliasing as defined by the standard. Since the segmentation fault happened on a pointer cast, namely:

```
struct regnode {
    U8  flags;
    U8  type;
    U16 next_off;
};
```

to

```
struct regnode_1 {
    U8  flags;
    U8  type;
    U16 next_off;
    U32 arg1;
};
```

However, enabling it with the `-fstrict-aliasing` flags didn't change anything. Although it qualifies as undefined behaviour, there is no overlap in memory, since the elements/nodes of the regular expression that is being currently parsed are laid out separately in memory.

Going deeper and checking the LLVM IR for the `switch` block in question, I got this in `regexec.ll`

```
; truncated
%876 = load %struct.regnode*, %struct.regnode** %scan, align 8, !dbg !8005
%877 = bitcast %struct.regnode* %876 to %struct.regnode_1*, !dbg !8005
%arg11715 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.regnode_1, %struct.regnode_1* %877, i32 0, i32 3, !dbg !8005
%878 = load i64, i64* %arg11715, align 8, !dbg !8005
store i64 %878, i64* %n, align 8, !dbg !8006
; truncated
```

The load/store instructions are using a 64-bit integer, which means that the pointer in C is interpreted as pointing to an 8 bytes integer (instead of 4). Thus, gathering 2 bytes outside the current regex node `struct` bounds for calculating the value of `arg1`. This value is in turn used as an array index which ultimately causes a segfault crash when it is out of array bounds.

Back to tracing where `U32` is interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned integer. Looking into file `spec_config.h`, the conditional compilation leads (at least in my machine) to a preprocessor block that starts with

```
#elif !defined(SPEC_CPU_GOOFY_DATAMODEL)
```

which, according to a code comment in the surrounding area, is supposed to correspond to a ILP32 data model (see also [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types)). However, `U32TYPE` is defined as an `unsigned long`, which on my machine is 64 bits.

So, the fix is to change the definition to

```
#define U32TYPE uint32_t
```

which, as stated in [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer), is guaranteed to be *exactly* 32 bits (if supported).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to complement the other answers by saying that it was enough for us to add `-DSPEC_CPU_LP64` to work around the segfault (`-DSPEC_LP64` in CPU2017). Would be nice if the SPEC group would add this to their FAQ. This also seems to  apply to `gcc`, `cactusADM`, `povray` and `wrf`.

We have a python script generating the config files for us, I'll talk to people and see if I can share what we have so far to get it running for our compiler.

Edit: Seems to be accesible from the outside anyway, so here you go: [`spec.py`](https://git.scc.kit.edu/IPDSnelting/spec.py/blob/9029decf173e3106317bce127943aabc9d516b2d/spec.py)

Comment: I'd swear that I couldn't find any relevant preprocessor def, but obviously, I must have missed something in the benchmark flag configuration file. I'll have another look your suggestion and report back when time permits.

Comment: Well, I was mostly prepping the script for CPU2017 when I hit that segfault, seemingly like the guy before me while adjusting it for 2006. I've no idea how I should've guessed the right flag out of the blue.